# Vuetify data table slow for large number of objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a custom object with a computed property...

```
class MyObject {
  get someComputedProp() {
    // expensive computation based on some other props
  }
}
```

and a vuetify data-table that contains ~500 of these objects

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="myObjects"
  :search="search"
>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="{ item }">
    <td>{{ item.someComputedProp }}</td>
...
```

The data table is very slow to load.  Experimenting, I found that my expensive getter is called about 4x per object in the entire table.  If I replace the code for my expensive getter with returning a string literal, my table is fast.  This brings up some questions:

1. Why is the getter called so many times per row?
2. The table has pagination, even if my getter must be called 4 times per row, why must it be called for every row, even those that are not on the current page?
3. I can have my object cache the expensive computation...

   ```
   get someComputedProp() {
     if (!this._cachedComputedProp)
       this._cachedComputedProp = // expensive computation based on some other props
     }
     return this._cachedComputedProp
   }
   ```

   which will make 3 out of the 4 calls cheap, but on another vue, I need the computed prop to update live as the props it depends on are updated.  Now I'm stuck doing this silliness...

   ```
   set propThatComputedPropDependsOn (value) {
     this._cachedComputedProp = null
     this._propThatComputedPropDependsOn = value
   }
   ```

   4. How do I get out of this mess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, maybe this will be useful to someone else:

1. I can't figure out why the getters are called so many times
2. I can't figure out why the data table builds everything in the dom, even stuff the user may never page to
3. I fixed my objects to (sometimes) cache expensive computation.

   ```
   // in constructor
   this.cacheProps = true

   get someComputedProp() {
     if (!this._cachedComputedProp || !this.cacheProps)
       this._cachedComputedProp = // expensive computation based on some other props
     }
     return this._cachedComputedProp
   }
   ```

In my editors, when I want the computed prop to be responsive, I set `cacheProps` to `false` on the object being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the configuration of the headers. You might need to explicitly set some columns as not sortable/searchable. That might be the reason why the property is being accessed multiple times.